# Gosu class vs enhancement

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I want to know the difference between Gosu class and enhancement. Because whatever we can do in enhancement, that we can do in Gosu class also then what is the need of Gosu Enhancement.

Answer (score 4):

Gosu class is just like a Java class.
What confuses you is the enhancement.

Enhancements are the extended properties of an OBJECT and are available for particular objects for which it is written for.

for example, lets say i need to write an function to check whether a number entered is greater than 10 or not.

So using gosu class, how we write the code is like

```
Class MyInteger(){
    static funtion isNoGreaterThan10(no : int) : boolean{
      return (no > 10) 
    }
}
```

and we call the function like:

```
MyInteger.isNoGreaterThan10(34) //returns a boolean value
```

So basically , the class and the method which we wrote are available anywhere in our application. Here comes the use of Enhancement

```
Enhancement MyInteger : int{
       funtion isNoGreaterThan10() : boolean{
          return (this > 10) //"this" represents the object upon which we are calling this enhancement
        }
}
```

The above enhancement is available for Integer objects only.
and all the functions inside this enhancement becomes the property of any integer object.

```
var number = 14
number.isNoGreaterThan10() //return True
```

The call be made even simpler like

```
36.isNoGreaterThan10() //return True

"my_name".isNoGreaterThan10() // is not possible as "my_name" is not an integer.
```

Similarly, lets see an enhancement for a string (say to get the length of a string)

```
Enhancement MyStringEnhancement : String {
  property get Length():int{
    return len(this)
  }
}
```

and the property Length() will be available for all string objects.

```
"Hello boss".Length // returns 10
```

hope this helps.

Aravind :)

Comment: so, similar to extension methods in c# then?

Answer (score 2):

**Find the Differences here follows.**

[image: Difference here follows]

Answer (score 1):

In an enhancement, it is not allowed to define any variable (No change for logging). Thus, enhancement should be used for simple aggregate calculation only. The advantage from enhancement is the new method is visible from the entity. If you define in Gosu class, you must know the class name.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of enhancement may be to extend the class which I do not have control over. For example, I am working on customization, and I need one more method on the class Contact. It's Guidewire's class, and I cannot modify it. Also it does not make much sense to create subclass and add the new method there, since such method would not be seen in existing Contact subclasses. But if I create enhancement, and add the method there, it will promptly be available in whole Contact subclass-tree, and I can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume it as extended attributes of an object (Fine tuning operation on top of an object or property that you wish to perform)

Answer (score 0):

- if the logic is reusable and generic we can place that in gosu class
- if the logic is intrinsically related to entity we can place it in
  enhacement class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).